# How can I set height of a second child base on height of "parent - first child" when first child is collapsible and has not fixed size

Tags: javascript, html, css

height of parent= 85vh,
height of child1: depends on that it is collapsed or not,
I need the height of child2 to be "height of (parent-child1)" and dynamically change according to the height of child1

```
<div id="parent" class="ibox-content" style="max-height:85vh;">
    <div id="child1" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="collapsiblePanel panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#collapseOne">
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2" ng-if="Members && Members.length>0">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `[ngClass]="otherThingIsCollapsed ? 'full-height' : 'half-height'"`?

Comment: and what is the value of height in these classes?

Comment: That's up to you, I guess something like `height: 90%` and `height: 50%`

Comment: Flxbox can do that IF the height of the parent is known...(not max-height....height).

Comment: I need the height of child2 to be exactly the "height of (parent-child1)", I can not use an estimated value

Comment: I`m using bootstrap 3 on the whole project and I can not use flexbox